# MS Access SQL error

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

This code is supposed to select the TOP 1, but it's not working properly. Instead of showing only the TOP 1 record, it is showing tons of records. It may be because I have 2 tables referenced. In another code I only had 1 and it worked. I need to reference table attendance though so I'm not sure how to work around that. Thanks!

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID 
FROM attendance, CFRRR 
WHERE [attendance.Programs] LIKE CFRRR.program  
AND [attendance.Language] LIKE CFRRR.language 
AND [attendance.Status] = 'Available' 
ORDER BY TS ASC
```

Here are the table fields for attendance: userID, username, Supervisor, Category, AttendanceDay, AttendanceTime, Programs, Language, Status, TS.

Here are the table fields for CFRRR: CFRRRID, WorkerID, Workeremail, Workername, Dateassigned, assignedby, RRRmonth, Scheduledate, scheduledtime, type, ScheduledType, caseid, language, lastname, firstname, Checkedin, Qid, status, CompletedType, comments, actiondate, verifduedate, program.

Clearly the last table has a lot of records.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working properly"? What output do you expect, and what do you get?

Comment: Please explain 'Not working properly'. Also, use proper joins. implicit joins are out of date for over 20 years now.

Comment: You guys are right, I'm sorry, I edited my question but here is what I added: Instead of showing only the TOP 1 record, it is showing tons of records when I run the query. Also @ZoharPeled I'm not exactly sure what you mean by proper joins. I'm new to MS Access so I don't know what's old style and what is new.

Comment: It is likely the case that you have many users with the same TS value ?

Comment: @Ala actually right now the records are 3, 4, 5, 6. So no one has the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT TOP` in MS Access differs from `SELECT TOP` in SQL Server and similar functionality in other databases.  It returns the top  rows based on the `order by`.  Then it continues to return rows that match the last value.  This is convenient sometimes, which is why SQL Server has this functionality as `SELECT TOP WITH TIES`.

To fix this, you need to include one or more columns that is unique for each generated row:

```
SELECT TOP 1 userID 
FROM attendance as a,
     CFRRR 
WHERE a.Programs LIKE CFRRR.program  AND
      a.Language LIKE CFRRR.language  AND
      a.Status = 'Available' 
ORDER BY TS ASC, userId, CFFRID
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff but I'm getting a syntax error and it is highlighting `CROSS`

Comment: @Lilly . . . I forgot that MS Access doesn't support this keyword which was just introduced into standard SQL about 23 years ago.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff that did get rid of the other UserID's from showing, but it's still populating over 200 records when it should only be 1.

Comment: @Lilly . . . Add more columns to the `ORDER BY` so each result row is identified once.  If you edit your question and provide sample data, then maybe it can be incorporated into an answer.

Comment: I updated my question to show both table's fields. Is that enough data to see what needs to be incorporated into the answer @Gordon Linoff?

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, would it be possible if you could assist me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292567/string-error-in-sql-ms-access It's an Update query with string errors.